# ¿Cómo acceder un dato de un arreglo de objetos en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, array

tengo una duda... Tengo el siguiente array de objetos:

```javascript
var celulares = [
   {"cel1":"62138844"},
   {"cel2":"65437712"},
   {"cel3":"60029011"}
];
```

Lo que quiero hacer es un recorrido dentro de ese array y encontrar un dato especifico, y si lo encuentra, detener el recorrido. Estoy utilizando un while para dicho fin ya que me permite utilizar la sentencia break para detener el recorrido. Sin embargo al ejecutar el código de igual forma me sigue haciendo el recorrido. Les dejo el código donde implemento el while a ver si estoy pasando algo por alto.

```js
var celulares = [
   {"cel1":"62138844"},
   {"cel2":"65437712"},
   {"cel3":"60029011"}
];
let i = 0;
while(i < celulares.length){
    if(celulares[i] === "60029011"){
      console.log(`Tu numero a llamar es: ${celulares[i]} `);
      i = celulares.length;
      break;
    }
    else{
    console.log(celulares[i]);
    i++
    }
}
```

Como información adicional, hice un recorrido con un array sencillo utilizando while y aplicando la misma lógica y hace lo que busco, asi que puede ser que el problema esté en como accedo los datos del array de objetos. Les agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda o comentario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### El problema

El problema es que `celulares` es un arreglo de objetos y tú lo estas tratando como un arreglo de `Strings`.

Tienes que hacer un par de cambios para que funcione.

### Explicación

1. En primer lugar, en tu arreglo `celulares`:

```javascript
var celulares = [
    {"cel1":"62138844"},
    {"cel2":"65437712"},
    {"cel3":"60029011"}
];
```

Cambiamos las keys de los objetos por `cell`, ya que no tiene mucho sentido tener una key diferente para cada número de celular. La cardinalidad nos la da el propio arreglo.

Esto sería:

```javascript
var celulares = [
   {"cell":"62138844"}, // todos los keys se los cambiamos por "cell" y no "cel1", "cel2", etc
   {"cell":"65437712"},
   {"cell":"60029011"}
];
```

2. Luego en la condición `if` de tu bucle `while`:

```javascript
if(celulares[i] === "60029011"){ // Estas tratando de comparar un objeto con una cadena de texto (Nunca te dará true)
      console.log(`Tu numero a llamar es: ${celulares[i]} `);
      i = celulares.length;
      break;
}
```

Le agregamos a `celulares[i]` el acceso a la key `cell`:

```javascript
if(celulares[i].cell === "60029011")
```

Y en el `console.log` tambien accedemos a la propiedad `cell`:

```javascript
console.log(`Tu numero a llamar es: ${celulares[i].cell} `);
```

---

### La solución

El código funcionando quedaría así:

```js
var celulares = [
   {"cell":"62138844"}, // todos los keys se los cambiamos por "cell" y no "cel1", "cel2", etc
   {"cell":"65437712"},
   {"cell":"60029011"},
   {"cell":"11111111"},
   {"cell":"22222222"} // Agrego mas números para que sea evidente que para antes
];
let i = 0;
while(i < celulares.length){
    if(celulares[i].cell === "60029011"){
      console.log(`Tu numero a llamar es: ${celulares[i].cell} `);
      i = celulares.length;
      break;
    }
    else{
    console.log(celulares[i]);
    i++
    }
}
```

### Recomendación

Si bien tu algoritmo te permite acceder a un item de un arreglo de objetos, te recomiendo que utilices los métodos que ya existen en javascript para tal fin.

En este caso podrías usar el método [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
 var celulares = [
     {"cell":"62138844"}, // todos los keys se los cambiamos por "cell" y no "cel1", "cel2", etc
     {"cell":"65437712"},
     {"cell":"60029011"},
     {"cell":"11111111"},
     {"cell":"22222222"} // Agrego mas números para que sea evidente que para antes
];

const numeroALlamar = celulares.find(item => item.cell == "60029011") // Si no encuentra ningún elemento, entonces devuelve "undefined"
console.log(`Tu numero a llamar es: ${numeroALlamar.cell} `);
```

Comment: Muy buena explicación y más por incluir la opción con `.find()`. Si acaso, solo faltó verificar que se encontró el elemento buscado.

Comment: Buen comentario, lo agrego a la respuesta

Answer (score -1):

Tu bucle no se detiene porque durante cada condicional if estas comparando **Object** con **'60029011'** y por eso nunca se detiene tu bucle, ya que la condición devuelve false.

Yo te recomiendo manejar el arreglo como lo dice el compañero Andres Gardiol, pero en caso de no ser posible, se soluciona de esta manera:

Se puede acceder a los objectos con los [] como si fueran arreglos, y asi apuntar a nombre de sus propiedades:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#enumerar_las_propiedades_de_un_objeto

```
let i = 0;

var celulares = [
  { cel1: "62138844" },
  { cel2: "65437712" },
  { cel3: "60029011" },
];

while (i < celulares.length) {
  const propertyName = `cel${i + 1}`; // su valor es : cel1, cel2, cel3... y va aumentando en cada iteración
  if (celulares[i][propertyName] === "60029011") {
    console.log(`Tu numero a llamar es: ${celulares[i]} `);
    i = celulares.length;
    break;
  } else {
    console.log(celulares[i]);
    i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Por cierto la linea i = celulares.length; sobra, la puedes eliminar y tu codigo seguira funcionando porque el break; finaliza la ejecucion de tu bucle sin importar que